# SQL - Updating a column when an other column on the same table is updated

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have this table :

[image]

I want every row in ***FooColumn2*** to be updated with the values of ***FooColumn1*** before insert and before update 
In MySql i have been doing this with *before insert* and *before update* triggers , although i have read that MS-SQL doesn't support that.

How can i do that in MS-SQL ?

Comment: Take a look at [`INSTEAD OF Triggers`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179288(v=sql.105).aspx) for SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to save the old value, just an Update trigger is required:

`CREATE TRIGGER trg_iu_TableName ON TableName
 INSTEAD OF UPDATE
 AS
 BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    Update t
    set t.Foocolumn1 = i.Foocolumn1
    set t.Foocolumn2 = t.Foocolumn1
    from TableName t
    inner join inserted i
    on t.idfoo=i.idfoo
 END`

..or if you want to set Foocolumn2 to the same as Foocolumn1 on Insert:

`CREATE TRIGGER trg_iu_TableName ON TableName
 INSTEAD OF UPDATE, INSERT
 AS
 BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    if (select count(*) from deleted) = 0
        Insert into Tablename (Foocolumn1, Foocolumn2)
            select Foocolumn1, Foocolumn1 from inserted 
    else
        Update t
        set t.Foocolumn1 = i.Foocolumn1
        set t.Foocolumn2 = t.Foocolumn1
        from TableName t
        inner join inserted i
        on t.idfoo=i.idfoo
 END`

Comment: Doesn't [Alex Lemesios](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2952709/alex-lemesios) want to put the "old" pre-update value of `Foocolumn1` put into `Foocolumn2`, so in the `UPDATE` statement he would want `SET Foocolumn2 = t.Foocolumn1` instead of `SET Foocolumn2 = i.Foocolumn1`?

Comment: Thank you. I have updated it to meet your interpretation. I was unsure because there was mention of 'before insert', which wouldn't make sense in this context.

Comment: I still think he wants to cover off both `UPDATE` and `INSERT`, so I would still include the `INSERT` section of the trigger if it was my answer.

Comment: I've updated is as per your suggestion.

Comment: This still assumes that on `INSERT` we want to ignore any value in `Foocolumn2` and just insert the `Foocolumn1` value into both fields - the desired behaviour in this instance may be to go ahead and insert any provided `Foocolumn2` value into that field in the table, it's not clear from the question IMO. I think this does answer the question though (I have upvoted), as it shows how `INSTEAD OF` triggers can be made to emulate `BEFORE` triggers - the specifics of the behaviour can be determined by [Alex Lemesios](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2952709/alex-lemesios) when he sees this.

Comment: Yes i want to cover up both Update and insert . Actually i want to sync the two columns . I have been trying the solution you gave above , but i get a syntax error here : set Foocolumn2 = t.Foocolumn1 . "Syntax error near "=" . I also get an other error on  set Foocolumn1 = i.Foocolumn1 " The multi-part identifier "i.Foocolumn1" cannot be bound

Comment: Alex, I have amended it. Hopefully it is fixed.